# A simplified regular expression matcher

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, reinventing-the-wheel, regex

I am working my way through some code challenges — partly to improve my problem solving, but also to improve my code quality.

I think my current (fully-functional) solution to a challenge is pretty solid, and fairly understandable. I would love to know, however, if there is anything in my style which could be improved.

Readers are encouraged to be opinionated, but to clearly-demarcate what is purely personal preference from what is a preference, but also strongly advised.

> Good morning! Here's your coding interview problem for today.
>
> This problem was asked by Facebook.
>
> Implement regular expression matching with the following special characters:
>
> `.` (period) which matches any single character
> `*` (asterisk) which matches zero or more of the preceding element
>
> That is, implement a function that takes in a string and a valid regular expression and returns whether or not the string matches the regular expression.
>
> For example, given the regular expression `"ra."` and the string `"ray"`, your function should return true. The same regular expression on the string `"Raymond"` should return false.
>
> Given the regular expression `".\*at"` and the string `"chat"`, your function should return true. The same regular expression on the string `"chats"` should return false.

```py
# solution.py

from collections import deque
import logging
from typing import Deque, NamedTuple, Optional, Union

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(funcName)s - %(lineno)d : %(message)s")

class Attempt(NamedTuple):
    matched_string : str
    remaining_string : str
    remaining_pattern : str

class DecisionPoint(NamedTuple):
    greedy : Attempt
    non_greedy : Attempt

def advance_attempt(attempt: Attempt, greedy = False) -> Attempt:
        char = attempt.remaining_pattern[0]

        if greedy and char!= '*':
            raise RuntimeError("Can't perform a greedy advancement on a non wildcard char.")

        new_matched_string = attempt.matched_string + char
        if greedy:
            new_remaining_pattern = attempt.remaining_pattern
        else:
            new_remaining_pattern = attempt.remaining_pattern[1:]
        new_remaining_string = attempt.remaining_string[1:]

        return Attempt(matched_string=new_matched_string,
                        remaining_pattern=new_remaining_pattern,
                        remaining_string=new_remaining_string)

def next_char_is_match(next_char : str, string : str) -> bool:
    """Returns true if the supplied next_char in the pattern matches the 
    head of the string. Next char is expected to be a single char or an 
    empty string."""

    if next_char == '':
        return False
    if next_char == '*':
        return True
    if next_char == '.' and len(string) != 0:
        return True
    return next_char == string[0]
    

def take_next_greedy(attempt: Attempt) -> Attempt:
    return advance_attempt(attempt=attempt,greedy=True)

def take_next_non_greedy(attempt : Attempt) -> Attempt:
    return advance_attempt(attempt)

def take_next(attempt : Attempt) -> Optional[Union[DecisionPoint,Attempt]]:
    """Returns None if no next match is possible; otherwise, returns either 
    a single progression of the attempt — i.e., a single character moved into
    the matched field from the remaining field — or, in the case of a wildcard,
    both the greedy and non-greedy next possibilities."""


    if (len(attempt.remaining_string) == 0 \
        or len(attempt.remaining_pattern) == 0):
        return None
    next_char_to_match_in_pattern = attempt.remaining_pattern[0]
    next_char_to_match_in_string = attempt.remaining_string[0]
    
    if next_char_to_match_in_pattern == '*':
        return DecisionPoint(greedy=take_next_greedy(attempt),
                             non_greedy=take_next_non_greedy(attempt))

    if (next_char_to_match_in_pattern == next_char_to_match_in_string\
        or next_char_to_match_in_pattern == '.'):
        return advance_attempt(attempt)
    
    
    
def main_loop(queue : Deque[Attempt]) -> bool:
        logging.debug(queue)
        logging.info(len(queue))

        attempt = queue.popleft()
        logging.info(attempt)

        if attempt.remaining_pattern == ''\
            and attempt.remaining_string == '':
            return True

        next_step = take_next(attempt)

        if next_step is None:
            return False
        elif isinstance(next_step,DecisionPoint):
            queue.appendleft(next_step.non_greedy)
            queue.appendleft(next_step.greedy)
            return False
        else:
            queue.appendleft(next_step)
            return False

def main(pattern : str, string : str) -> bool:
    q = deque()
    q.append(Attempt(matched_string='',
                     remaining_string=string,
                     remaining_pattern=pattern))
    match_found = False
    while len(q) != 0 and not match_found:
        match_found = main_loop(q)
        
    logging.info(match_found) 
    return match_found

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main('.*at*.rq','chatsdafrzafafrq')
```

```py
# tests.py

import unittest

from .solution import main


class BasicTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_given_which_is_expected_to_match_matches(self):
        computed_result = main('ra.','ray')
        self.assertTrue(computed_result)

    def test_given_which_is_expected_to_not_match_does_not_match(self):
        computed_result = main('ra.','raymond')
        self.assertFalse(computed_result)

    def test_other_given_which_is_expected_to_match_matches(self):
        computed_result = main('.*at','chat')
        self.assertTrue(computed_result)
    
    def test_complex_which_is_expected_to_match_matches(self):
        computed_result = main('.*jk*.wee*.weq','jkhkh;llkjkljklkjljl;weeklsfdjdsfj;weq')
        self.assertTrue(computed_result)

    def test_complex_which_is_expected_not_to_match_does_not_match(self):
        computed_result = main('.*jk*.wee*.weqr','jkhkh;llkjkljklkjljl;weeklsfdjdsfj;weqtjhuafjs')
        self.assertFalse(computed_result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) as well as  [_what you may and may not do after receiving answers_](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## PEP 8

The [Style Guide for Python Code](https://pep8.org/) enumerates several conventions for Python programs

### Imports

All `import ...` statements should precede `from ... import ...`

Reading through the PEP 8 documentation, I'm not seeing this, but my pylinter complains if this ordering is not obeyed.

### Indentation

> Use 4 spaces per indentation level.

Functions like `advance_attempt` are indented too far.

### Code Organization

- Imports
- Classes & function definitions
- Code

Your `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, ...)` statement falls under the "Code" category, and should be after the class/function definitions.

Moreover, it is **EXECUTED** when the module is imported.  It should be inside the main-guard, to prevent unexpected side-effects.

### Spaces

#### Comma

`logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,format="...`

There should be a space after every comma.

#### Binary operators

`if greedy and char!= '*':`

There should be a space on both sides of the binary operator `!=`.

#### Type Hints

`def take_next_non_greedy(attempt : Attempt) -> Attempt:`

There should be no space before the `:`

## Unnecessary line continuations

```py
    if (len(attempt.remaining_string) == 0 \
        or len(attempt.remaining_pattern) == 0):
        return None
```

There is no need for the `\`, since the expression is inside parenthesis.

## Broken implementation

Why is `'.*jk*.wee*.weq'` expected to match `'jkhkh;llkjkljklkjljl;weeklsfdjdsfj;weq'`?

That pattern is:

- `.*` any number of any character
- `j` a single j
- `k*` 0 or more k's
- `.` any character
- `we` two explicit characters
- `e*` any number of e's
- `.` any character
- `weq` three explicit characters

The given string does **not** match that pattern.  The test asserts that it should match.  If the pattern was written with `.*` instead of `*.` patterns, I could actually see the match succeeding.  But it wasn't. Assuming a match is declared (I haven't run the code), then the implementation must be broken.

Comment: Appreciated! I was already aware of PEP8, but I didn't realise that it recommended putting all imports .... before from ... import ...

Broken Implementation: I think I actually misread the brief:  I thought that * matches any character, not that is matched any number of the preceding character. I'm not sure why I didn't realise that, given that that is how actual regex definitions work.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here is an updated answer which incorporates the feedback:

```py
# solution.py
from __future__ import annotations

import logging
from collections import deque
from typing import Deque, List,NamedTuple, Optional, Union


class Attempt(NamedTuple):
    matched_string : str
    remaining_string : str
    remaining_tokens : List[Token]

class DecisionPoint(NamedTuple):
    greedy : Attempt
    non_greedy : Attempt

class Token(NamedTuple):
    character : str
    is_wildcarded : bool = False

def tokenize(pattern: str) -> List[Token]:
    tokens = []
    while pattern:
        if len(pattern) == 1:
            tokens.append(Token(character=pattern))
            pattern = ''
        else:
            head = pattern[0]
            pattern = pattern[1:]
            if pattern[0] == '*':
                pattern = pattern[1:]
                tokens.append(Token(character=head,
                                    is_wildcarded=True))
            else:
                tokens.append(Token(character=head))
    return tokens

def advance_attempt(attempt: Attempt, greedy: bool = False) -> Attempt:
        next_token = attempt.remaining_tokens[0]
        char = next_token.character

        new_matched_string = attempt.matched_string + char
        if greedy:
            new_remaining_tokens = attempt.remaining_tokens
        else:
            new_remaining_tokens = attempt.remaining_tokens[1:]
        new_remaining_string = attempt.remaining_string[1:]

        return Attempt(matched_string=new_matched_string,
                        remaining_tokens=new_remaining_tokens,
                        remaining_string=new_remaining_string)

def next_token_is_match(next_token: Token, string: str) -> bool:
    """Returns true if the supplied next_char in the pattern matches the 
    head of the string. Next char is expected to be a single char or an 
    empty string."""

    if next_token.character == '.':
        return True
    return next_token.character == string[0]
    

def take_next_greedy(attempt: Attempt) -> Attempt:
    return advance_attempt(attempt=attempt,greedy=True)

def take_next_non_greedy(attempt: Attempt) -> Attempt:
    return advance_attempt(attempt)

def take_next(attempt : Attempt) -> Optional[Union[DecisionPoint,Attempt]]:
    """Returns None if no next match is possible; otherwise, returns either 
    a single progression of the attempt — i.e., a single character moved into
    the matched field from the remaining field — or, in the case of a wildcard,
    both the greedy and non-greedy next possibilities."""


    if (len(attempt.remaining_string) == 0 
        or len(attempt.remaining_tokens) == 0):
        return None
    next_token_to_match_in_pattern = attempt.remaining_tokens[0]
    next_char_to_match_in_string = attempt.remaining_string[0]
    
    if next_token_to_match_in_pattern.is_wildcarded:
        return DecisionPoint(greedy=take_next_greedy(attempt),
                             non_greedy=take_next_non_greedy(attempt))

    if (next_token_to_match_in_pattern.character == next_char_to_match_in_string
        or next_token_to_match_in_pattern.character == '.'):
        return advance_attempt(attempt)
    
    
    
def main_loop(queue: Deque[Attempt]) -> bool:
        logging.debug(queue)
        logging.info(len(queue))

        attempt = queue.popleft()
        logging.info(attempt)

        if (attempt.remaining_tokens == []
            and attempt.remaining_string == ''):
            return True

        next_step = take_next(attempt)

        if next_step is None:
            return False
        elif isinstance(next_step,DecisionPoint):
            queue.appendleft(next_step.non_greedy)
            queue.appendleft(next_step.greedy)
            return False
        else:
            queue.appendleft(next_step)
            return False

def main(pattern: str, string : str) -> bool:
    q = deque()
    q.append(Attempt(matched_string='',
                     remaining_string=string,
                     remaining_tokens=tokenize(pattern)))
    match_found = False
    while len(q) != 0 and not match_found:
        match_found = main_loop(q)
        
    logging.info(match_found) 
    return match_found

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(funcName)s\
                        - %(lineno)d : %(message)s")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main('.*at.*rq','chatsdatfrzafafrq')
```

```py
# tests.py

import unittest

from .solution import main, tokenize, Token


class TestTokenize(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_basic(self):
        test_pattern = 'a*.d.*'
        expected_result = [Token('a',True),
                           Token('.'),
                           Token('d'),
                           Token('.',True)
                          ]

        computed_result = tokenize(test_pattern)

        self.assertEqual(expected_result,computed_result)
class TestSolution(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_given_which_is_expected_to_match_matches(self):
        computed_result = main('ra.','ray')
        self.assertTrue(computed_result)

    def test_given_which_is_expected_to_not_match_does_not_match(self):
        computed_result = main('ra.','raymond')
        self.assertFalse(computed_result)

    def test_other_given_which_is_expected_to_match_matches(self):
        computed_result = main('.*at','chat')
        self.assertTrue(computed_result)
    
    def test_complex_which_is_expected_to_match_matches(self):
        computed_result = main('.*jk.*wee*.*weq','jkhkh;llkjkljklkjljl;weeklsfdjdsfj;weq')
        self.assertTrue(computed_result)

    def test_complex_which_is_expected_not_to_match_does_not_match(self):
        computed_result = main('.*jk*.wee.*weqr','jkhkh;llkjkljklkjljl;weeklsfdjdsfj;weqtjhuafjs')
        self.assertFalse(computed_result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: FYI the updated implementation doesn't implement `*` matching 0 of the preceding character. For example, `main('.*chat','chat')` returns `False` when it should return `True`.

Answer (score 0):

This has been very illuminating in that it highlights that even a fairly simple brief can have all kinds of corner cases which must be considered in testing.

Hopefully, this solution is the one final one.

```py
# solution.py
from __future__ import annotations

import logging
from collections import deque
from typing import Deque, List, NamedTuple, Optional, Union


class Attempt(NamedTuple):
    matched_string: str
    remaining_string: str
    remaining_tokens: List[Token]


class DecisionPoint(NamedTuple):
    greedy: Attempt
    non_greedy: Attempt


class Token(NamedTuple):
    character: str
    is_starred: bool = False


def tokenize(pattern: str) -> List[Token]:
    tokens = []
    while pattern:
        if len(pattern) == 1:
            tokens.append(Token(character=pattern))
            pattern = ''
        else:
            head = pattern[0]
            pattern = pattern[1:]
            if pattern[0] == '*':
                pattern = pattern[1:]
                tokens.append(Token(character=head,
                                    is_starred=True))
            else:
                tokens.append(Token(character=head))
    return tokens


def advance_attempt_starred(attempt: Attempt, greedy: bool = False) -> Attempt:
    next_token = attempt.remaining_tokens[0]
    next_token_char = next_token.character

    new_matched_string = attempt.matched_string + next_token_char
    if greedy:
        new_remaining_tokens = attempt.remaining_tokens
        new_remaining_string = attempt.remaining_string[1:]
    else:
        new_remaining_tokens = attempt.remaining_tokens[1:]
        new_remaining_string = attempt.remaining_string

    return Attempt(matched_string=new_matched_string,
                   remaining_tokens=new_remaining_tokens,
                   remaining_string=new_remaining_string)


def advance_attempt(attempt: Attempt, greedy: bool = False) -> Attempt:
    next_token = attempt.remaining_tokens[0]
    next_token_char = next_token.character

    new_matched_string = attempt.matched_string + next_token_char
    new_remaining_tokens = attempt.remaining_tokens[1:]
    new_remaining_string = attempt.remaining_string[1:]

    return Attempt(matched_string=new_matched_string,
                   remaining_tokens=new_remaining_tokens,
                   remaining_string=new_remaining_string)




def take_next_greedy(attempt: Attempt) -> Attempt:
    return advance_attempt_starred(attempt, greedy=True)


def take_next_non_greedy(attempt: Attempt, starred: bool = False) -> Attempt:
    if starred:
        return advance_attempt_starred(attempt)
    return advance_attempt(attempt)


def take_next(attempt: Attempt) -> Optional[Union[DecisionPoint, Attempt]]:
    """Returns None if no next match is possible; otherwise, returns either 
    a single progression of the attempt — i.e., a single character moved into
    the matched field from the remaining field — or, in the case of a wildcard,
    both the greedy and non-greedy next possibilities."""

    if (len(attempt.remaining_string) == 0
            or len(attempt.remaining_tokens) == 0):
        return None
    next_token_to_match_in_pattern = attempt.remaining_tokens[0]
    next_char_to_match_in_string = attempt.remaining_string[0]

    if next_token_to_match_in_pattern.is_starred:
        return DecisionPoint(greedy=take_next_greedy(attempt),
                             non_greedy=take_next_non_greedy(attempt,
                                                             starred=True))

    if (next_token_to_match_in_pattern.character == next_char_to_match_in_string
            or next_token_to_match_in_pattern.character == '.'):
        return take_next_non_greedy(attempt)


def main_loop(queue: Deque[Attempt]) -> bool:
    logging.debug(queue)
    logging.info(len(queue))

    attempt = queue.popleft()
    logging.info(attempt)

    if (attempt.remaining_tokens == []
            and attempt.remaining_string == ''):
        return True

    next_step = take_next(attempt)

    if next_step is None:
        return False
    elif isinstance(next_step, DecisionPoint):
        queue.appendleft(next_step.non_greedy)
        queue.appendleft(next_step.greedy)
        return False
    else:
        queue.appendleft(next_step)
        return False


def main(pattern: str, string: str) -> bool:
    q = deque()
    q.append(Attempt(matched_string='',
                     remaining_string=string,
                     remaining_tokens=tokenize(pattern)))
    match_found = False
    while len(q) != 0 and not match_found:
        match_found = main_loop(q)

    logging.info(match_found)
    return match_found


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(funcName)s\
                        - %(lineno)d : %(message)s")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main('.*at.*rq', 'chatsdatfrzafafrq')
```

```py
# solution.py
import unittest

from .solution import main, tokenize, Token


class TestTokenize(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_basic(self):
        test_pattern = 'a*.d.*'
        expected_result = [Token('a',True),
                           Token('.'),
                           Token('d'),
                           Token('.',True)
                          ]

        computed_result = tokenize(test_pattern)

        self.assertEqual(expected_result,computed_result)

class TestSolution(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_given_which_is_expected_to_match_matches(self):
        computed_result = main('ra.','ray')
        self.assertTrue(computed_result)

    def test_given_which_is_expected_to_not_match_does_not_match(self):
        computed_result = main('ra.','raymond')
        self.assertFalse(computed_result)

    def test_other_given_which_is_expected_to_match_matches(self):
        computed_result = main('.*at','chat')
        self.assertTrue(computed_result)
    
    def test_complex_which_is_expected_to_match_matches(self):
        computed_result = main('.*jk.*wee*.*weq','jkhkh;llkjkljklkjljl;weeklsfdjdsfj;weq')
        self.assertTrue(computed_result)

    def test_complex_which_is_expected_not_to_match_does_not_match(self):
        computed_result = main('.*jk*.wee.*weqr','jkhkh;llkjkljklkjljl;weeklsfdjdsfj;weqtjhuafjs')
        self.assertFalse(computed_result)

    def test_starred_consumes_none_or_many(self):
        computed_result = main('.*chat','chat')
        self.assertTrue(computed_result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: This is very close, I think you just need to cover one more test case: `main('.*', '')` being `True` and then it should be complete.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few bugs that are still there starting from the original implementation, so I'm posting this as a late review because this won't fit in a comment. The shape of `Attempt` has changed from the original with the most recent updates from @Moye, but the root causes of the bugs are essentially the same.

Let's temporarily add some debugging print statements to `take_next`:

```python
def take_next(attempt: Attempt) -> Optional[Union[DecisionPoint, Attempt]]:
    """Returns None if no next match is possible; otherwise, returns either 
    a single progression of the attempt — i.e., a single character moved into
    the matched field from the remaining field — or, in the case of a wildcard,
    both the greedy and non-greedy next possibilities."""

    print(attempt)

    if (len(attempt.remaining_string) == 0
            or len(attempt.remaining_tokens) == 0):
        print("  No next steps.")
        return None
    next_token_to_match_in_pattern = attempt.remaining_tokens[0]
    next_char_to_match_in_string = attempt.remaining_string[0]

    if next_token_to_match_in_pattern.is_starred:
        greedy = take_next_greedy(attempt)
        non_greedy = take_next_non_greedy(attempt, starred=True)
        print(f"      greedy --> {greedy}")
        print(f"  non-greedy --> {non_greedy}")
        return DecisionPoint(greedy=greedy, non_greedy=non_greedy)

    if (next_token_to_match_in_pattern.character == next_char_to_match_in_string
            or next_token_to_match_in_pattern.character == '.'):
        next_step = take_next_non_greedy(attempt)
        print(f"  --> {next_step}")
        return next_step

    print("  No next steps.")
```

---

The first bug: when comparing with a starred character in the pattern, we don't check if that character is the same as the current character in the string (either that, or if the starred character is the wildcard `.`).

For example, for `main(pattern='x*', string='a')`, we have:

```
Attempt(matched_string='', remaining_string='a', remaining_tokens=[Token(character='x', is_starred=True)])
      greedy --> Attempt(matched_string='x', remaining_string='', remaining_tokens=[Token(character='x', is_starred=True)])
  non-greedy --> Attempt(matched_string='x', remaining_string='a', remaining_tokens=[])
Attempt(matched_string='x', remaining_string='', remaining_tokens=[Token(character='x', is_starred=True)])
  No next steps.
Attempt(matched_string='x', remaining_string='a', remaining_tokens=[])
  No next steps.
```

- The greedy next step consumed `a` from the string, which shouldn't have happened given that the pattern is `x*`.
- The non-greedy next step didn't consume any characters from the string yet it has `matched_string='x'`. Only `matched_string` being wrong here makes this more of a cosmetic issue since the implementation doesn't depend on the value of `matched_string` for decision making.
- Examining an `Attempt` with `remaining_string='', remaining_tokens=[Token(character='x', is_starred=True)]` yields no next steps, which is incorrect. This is actually a concrete example of the second bug; more on this below.

For this query the implementation returns the correct answer of `False`, but for the wrong reasons.

---

The second bug: `take_next` immediately concludes that there are no valid next steps if either of the following are true:

- `attempt.remaining_string` is an empty string
- `attempt.remaining_tokens` is empty

This is incorrect because even if `attempt.remaining_string` is an empty string, we can still have a match if all the tokens in `attempt.remaining_tokens` are starred.

So for `main(pattern='.*', string='')`,

```
Attempt(matched_string='', remaining_string='', remaining_tokens=[Token(character='.', is_starred=True)])
  No next steps.
```

the current implementation doesn't see a path forward from an `Attempt` with an empty `remaining_string` and immediately returns `None` from `take_next`. What it should return is `Attempt(matched_string='', remaining_string='', remaining_tokens=[])`.

To summarize what we can conclude based on the state of `Attempt`:

| `Attempt` state | Conclusion |
| --- | --- |
| `remaining_string==''` and `remaining_tokens==[]` | pattern successfully matches the string (which you've correctly covered in `main_loop`) |
| `remaining_string==''` and `remaining_tokens` is not empty | could have next valid steps; must inspect further to find out |
| `remaining_string` is not empty and `remaining_tokens==[]` | no possible next valid steps |
| `remaining_string` is not empty and `remaining_tokens` is not empty | could have next valid steps; must inspect further to find out |